# Link OnClick code behind does not execute when set as ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I did a lot of searching and cannot figure this out.

I have a ModalPopupExtender pop-up that I want to display when the user clicks a link DoSomething. The pop-up has a dropdown control that I then want to populate on the fly when the user asks to open the dialogue. This needs to happen server side via the code behind. Currently I am trying to do it via an OnClick event on the link but as soon as the link is tied to the ModalPopupExtender the link OnClick code is not executed.

**Code snippet:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoSomething" runat="server" onClick="lnkDoSomething_Click">Do Something</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpelnklnkDoSomething" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="lnkDoSomething"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDragHandlerForlnkDoSomething"   
    TargetControlID="lnklnkDoSomething"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The problem is as soon as I set the ModalPopupExtender to the link the OnClick code does not execute. This obviously is by design but it doesn't make sense to me (naive) as if the user clicks the link the OnClick code should be executed.

Any ideas why this is not supported and what the correct solution is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attach the `ModalPopupExtender` to a dummy button and show the modal on the `LinkButton`'s `OnClick` even from the code-behind:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoSomething" runat="server" onClick="lnkDoSomething_Click">Do Something</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button id="dummyButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpelnklnkDoSomething" runat="server" 
  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="controlToPopUpId"
  PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDragHandlerForlnkDoSomething" 
  TargetControlID="dummyButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
  protected void lnkDoSomething_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     //do work
     mpelnklnkDoSomething.Show();
  }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Rick it works. On a related note do you know "why" we need to attach to a dummy button? This appears like it is essentially a work around so I am wondering if there is a core ASP design reason why does not allow it on the link

Comment: When you associate the button/linkbutton, the ModalPopUpExtender takes over the client side onclick event to do the "popup".  It returns false which cancels the actual client side click event.  The dummy button is really needed by ASP.NET, probably an interface it implements, so it can wire up events though the ASP.NET page life-cycle.